# c# Canvas Zoom Functionality issue ?Not able to zoom out to original postion after zooming in to a point using matrix transform

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, zooming, mousewheel

I'm trying to implement a canvas zoom functionality in c# using matrix transform. I'm able to zoom in to one particular point, but while zooming out to the original scale(i've limited to original scale) the position of the canvas changes(out of the window) . I would like it to zoom out to its original position. Can anyone help?

Please find the code below:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="C1_S" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
                    <Canvas Name="canvas_core0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="600" Width="1000000" MouseWheel="Canvas_MouseWheel" ClipToBounds="True" >
                        <Canvas.Background>
                            <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,20,40,40" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    <GeometryDrawing>
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50"/>
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                            <Pen Brush="Gray" Thickness=".1"/>
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                            </DrawingBrush>
                        </Canvas.Background>
                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <MatrixTransform/>
                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    </Canvas>
                </ScrollViewer>
```

C# Code:`

```
        private void Canvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = sender as UIElement;
        var position = e.GetPosition(element);
        if(e.Delta>0)
        {
            previousposition = position;
        }
        var transform = element.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;
        var matrix = transform.Matrix;
        scrollcountprevious = scrollcountcurrent;
        scrollcountcurrent = scrollcountcurrent + e.Delta;
       // var scale1 = scrollcountcurrent > scrollcountprevious ? 1.1 : scrollcountcurrent <scrollcountprevious0 ? 1.0 : (1.0 / 1.1); // choose appropriate scaling factor
        var scale1=1.0;
        if (scrollcountcurrent > scrollcountprevious)
        {
            scale1 = 1.1;
            matrix.ScaleAtPrepend(scale1, scale1, position.X, position.Y);
            transform.Matrix = matrix;
        }
        else if (scrollcountcurrent < scrollcountprevious&&scrollcountcurrent>=0)
        {
            scale1 = 1 / 1.1;
             matrix.ScaleAtPrepend(scale1, scale1, previousposition.X, previousposition.Y);
        transform.Matrix = matrix;

        }
        else
        {
            scale1 = 1;
            scrollcountcurrent = 0;
            matrix.ScaleAtPrepend(scale1, scale1, previousposition.X, previousposition.Y);
            transform.Matrix = matrix;
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Clemens  Please find the xaml below.

Comment: @Clemens.. I'm sorry, i've changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand what you're exactly trying to achieve. Also, having the Canvas in a ScrollViewer might mess things up.

But probably this MouseWheel handler does what you want:

```
private double scale = 1;

private void Canvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (UIElement)sender;
    var position = e.GetPosition(element);
    var matrix = Matrix.Identity;

    scale = Math.Max(e.Delta > 0 ? scale * 1.1 : scale / 1.1, 1.0);
    matrix.ScaleAt(scale, scale, position.X, position.Y);

    ((MatrixTransform)element.RenderTransform).Matrix = matrix;
}
```

In order to also scale the actual size of the Canvas in the ScrollViewer, scale its `LayoutTransform` instead of the `RenderTransform`:

```
<Canvas.LayoutTransform>
    <MatrixTransform/>
</Canvas.LayoutTransform>

private void Canvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var position = e.GetPosition(element);
    var matrix = Matrix.Identity;

    scale = Math.Max(e.Delta > 0 ? scale * 1.1 : scale / 1.1, 1.0);
    matrix.ScaleAt(scale, scale, position.X, position.Y);

    ((MatrixTransform)element.LayoutTransform).Matrix = matrix;
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly...but the scroll bars of the canvas are not scaled to the new value. I tried to use scaletransform but its not working

Comment: Use LayoutTransform instead of RenderTransform.

Comment: I have noticed one thing, its not zooming to the area where the mouse is pointed, as in its always zoom towards the middle irrespective of the position of the mouse pointer . Is it really possible to have both scaling of the scroll bars and zooming to one particular point?

Comment: That's why I said "having the Canvas in a ScrollViewer might mess things up". You would have to adjust the scrolled position programatically.